# Is there anyway to manually cache remote artifacts in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jcenter

I am playing with a brand new `OOS`  [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory) installation. I have a remote repository for [[image]jcenter](/questions/tagged/jcenter). I am looking for a way to manually cache remote artifacts to `jcenter-cach` with [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory) web UI. I appreciate any help.

```
Edit remote Repository
```

[image]

```
Repository Brower
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your build is resolving artifacts from [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory)  , `Artifactory` will cache artifacts that were requested from remote repositories.

But since you are looking for a way to do this manually with `Artifactory` ***Web UI*** , it can be don't even though it is little bit tricky.( **NB:** Remote Web search capability should be enabled in your `Artifactory` instance). Here are the steps to do so:-

1. Click **Artifacts** tab
2. Select **Remote Search**  (this will open a window for search artifacts from [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray)’s remote [[image]jcenter](/questions/tagged/jcenter) repository )
3. Find the artifact you wants to cache
4. When you find the artifact, click it , a `pop up` will appear and select **Download**.

This will download the file to your local machine and at the same time it will trigger Artifactory to catch the same artifact to remote cache.

> **NB:** Be advised that caching artifacts may take a while depending on the file size or internet connection speed.